# Prometheus configuration for monitoring Orleans in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, orleans

I'm trying to get Prometheus functioning with my Orleans silos...

1. I use [this](https://github.com/zh6335901/Orleans.TelemetryConsumers.Prometheus) consumer to expose Orleans metrics for Prometheus on port 8082. With a local Prometheus instance and using the grafana.json from the same repository I see that it works.

   ```
     _ = builder.AddPrometheusTelemetryConsumerWithSelfServer(port: 8082);
   ```
2. Following [this guide](https://devopscube.com/setup-prometheus-monitoring-on-kubernetes/) to install Prometheus on Kubernetes on a different namespace that my silos are deployed.
3. Following instructions I added the prometheus labels to my orleans deployment yaml:

   ```
     spec:
      replicas: 2
      selector:
        matchLabels:
        app: mysilo
      template:
        metadata:
          annotations:
            prometheus.io/scrape: 'true'
            prometheus.io/port: '8082'
          labels:
            app: mysilo
   ```

My job in prometheus yml:

```
    - job_name: "orleans"
      kubernetes_sd_configs:
        - role: pod
          namespaces:
            names:
              - orleans
          selectors:
            - role: "pod"
              label: "app=mysilo"
```

According to the same guide, all the pods metrics get discovered if "the pod metadata is annotated with prometheus.io/scrape and prometheus.io/port annotations.". I assume I don't need any extra installations.

With all this, and port forwarding my prometheus pod, I can see prometheus is working in http://localhost:9090/metrics but no metrics are being shown in my grafana dashboard (again, I could make it work in local machine with only one silo).

When exploring grafana I find that it seems it can't find the instances:

```
    sum(rate(process_cpu_seconds_total{job=~"orleans", instance=~"()"}[3m])) * 100
```

The aim is to monitor resources my orleans silos are using (not the pods metrics themselves, but orleans metrics), but I'm missing something :(

Comment: can you shell into the silo pod and curl the metrics endpoint?  localhost:8082/metrics.   Perhaps your prometheus doesnt have the targets set right.  check the targets via http://localhost:9090/targets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @BozoJoe's comment I could debug this.

The problem was that it was trying to scrape ports 30000 and 1111 instead of 8082 like I said before. I could see this thanks to the Prometheus dashboard at localhost:9090/targets

So I went to prometheus config file and make sure to start scrapping the correct port (also I added some restrictions to the search for name):

```
  - job_name: "orleans"
    kubernetes_sd_configs:
     - role: pod
       namespaces:
         names:
          - orleans
       selectors:
          - role: "pod"
            label: "app=mysilo"
    relabel_configs:
    - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_name]
      action: keep   
      regex: 'my-silo-name*'
    - source_labels: [__address__]
      action: replace
      regex: ([^:]+):.*
      replacement: $1:8081
      target_label: __address__
```